# Need to show some divs loading one after another, top to botton using transforms or transitions

Tags: css, animation

Need to show some divs loading one after another, top to bottom using transforms or transitions, without using positions (relative or absolute). In my case the divs are showing one after another from bottom to top, but I'm not able to change it to reverse to top to bottom without using position.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
}
[class^="c"] {
  animation: slide 0.5s linear both;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-5vh);
}
[class^="c"]:nth-last-of-type(10) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}
[class^="c"]:nth-last-of-type(9) {
  animation-delay: 9s;
}
[class^="c"]:nth-last-of-type(8) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
[class^="c"]:nth-last-of-type(7) {
  animation-delay: 7s;
}
[class^="c"]:nth-last-of-type(6) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
[class^="c"]:nth-last-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
[class^="c"]:nth-last-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
[class^="c"]:nth-last-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
[class^="c"]:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
[class^="c"]:nth-last-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    filter: blur(1em);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cardWrap">
  <div class="card">itin 1</div>
  <div class="card">itin 2</div>
  <div class="card">itin 3</div>
  <div class="card">itin 4</div>
  <div class="card">itin 5</div>
  <div class="card">itin 6</div>
  <div class="card">itin 7</div>
  <div class="card">itin 8</div>
  <div class="card">itin 9</div>
  <div class="card">itin 10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Multiple Complex and Invalid CSS Selectors

The syntax was very wrong:

> ```
> [class^="c"]:nth-last-of-type(2) {
>   animation-delay: 2s;
> }
> ```

Should be:

> ```
> .card:nth-of-type(2) {
>   animation-delay: 2s;
> }
> ```

It works perfectly.

- So for classes just prefix with a dot: **.**`className`

---

- While there is `:last-of-type` pseudo-class the logic behind `:nth-last-of-type(2)` totally escapes me.
- **nth** ...  represents a number of unknown value, it can be 1, 2, 3, ...8,004.006 etc. The ordinal  gives us th hint that we are dealing with the numbered order of items.

> ```
> /* This is the first tag of an identical group of siblings */
>
> :first-of-type /*OR*/ :nth-of-type(1)
> ```

---

> ```
> /* The number indicated within the parenthesis indicate the position a tag is in amongst
>  it's identical siblings.*/
>
> :nth-of-type(2)  // This would be the second tag of a group of identical sibling tags.
> ```

---

> ```
> /* While :first-of-type has its uses, the `:last-of-type` even moreso. Don't think of it
>   as a number, think of it as the only sibling that has no sibling after it and has 
>  all of the siblings preceding it.*/
>
> :last-of-type
> ```

### *"...tag of an identical group of siblings"*

### Demo

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
}

.card {
  animation: slide 0.5s linear both;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-5vh);
}

.card:nth-of-type(10) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(9) {
  animation-delay: 9s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(8) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(7) {
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    filter: blur(1em);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cardWrap">
  <div class="card">itin 1</div>
  <div class="card">itin 2</div>
  <div class="card">itin 3</div>
  <div class="card">itin 4</div>
  <div class="card">itin 5</div>
  <div class="card">itin 6</div>
  <div class="card">itin 7</div>
  <div class="card">itin 8</div>
  <div class="card">itin 9</div>
  <div class="card">itin 10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Zer00ne! This almost worked for me. My problem now is that The last in this case number 10 has to show first on the top and pushed/followed by 9, 8,7... Do you have any idea how I can do that? Thanks one more time.